# ExtJS with Squash Javascript Obfuscator

Tags: javascript, extjs, obfuscation

I stumbled upon this javascript obfuscator called [Squash](http://www.ideareactor.com/idea/HomePage.html), I want to use it on my ExtJS project to obfuscate my javascript files. I've tried it and the result are totally obfuscated codes. But it seems that I have to obfuscate the ExtJS library too because I got warnings that it couldn't find functions such as `Ext.onReady()`, `Ext.form.FormPanel()`, etc.

I just want to ask if any of you guys have successfully used Squash + ExtJS in a project and how did you manage to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest another javascript obfuscation tool: http://jscrambler.com.

The tool is able to detect and replace identifiers with private access so you can/should only obfuscate your extjs application.

Comment: Great tool with great API client.

Answer (score 1):

Typical rtfm: The `@Public` annotation on the `setDocumentTitle` function prevents the function name from being obfuscated so that it can be accessed from unobfuscated code.

Answer (score 0):

try 
http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ 
with check on 
Base62 encode
Shrink variables
it worked for me on my extjs application with out the need for to obfuscate the ExtJS library too